# check consecutive number in two lists

Tags: python

pseudocode:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
B = [4,5,6,7,1,2,6,7,8]

count = 0

for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(B)):
        if A[i:i+3] == B[j:j+3]: #check 3 consecutive numbers if are equal
            count += 1
            print x[i:i+3]
print count
```

Question: how can I implement when `A[4,5,6] == B[4,5,6]`, then skip to `A[6,7,8]==B[6,7,8]`, instead of `A[5,6,7]==B[5,6,7]`

Comment: Start with explaining what you want. I don't understand at all

Comment: Just check whether it’s `6, 7, 8` and don’t `print` or increment `count`?

Comment: Why don't you want [5,6,7]?

Comment: Are you aware that you can also get sublists that are shorter than three with this approach? Slice lengths aren't fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flag variable:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
B = [4,5,6,7,1,2,6,7,8]

count = 0
skip = False #this is a flag variable

for i in range(len(A)):
    for j in range(len(B)):
        if skip:
            skip = False
            continue
        if A[i:i+3] == B[j:j+3]: #check 3 consecutive numbers if are equal
            count += 1
            print x[i:i+3]
            skip = True 


print count
```

Comment: It skips only one, though - what if there is a sequence like `1,2,3,4,5` in both lists? Also, `x` is still undefined.